# Facebook Authorization url, scoped authorization url and token url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to write a java code to get the access token of facebook in order to do operation in it using graph API.For that I need to know the Facebook Authorization url, scoped authorization url and token url?

Kindly, specify those urls.

Comment: Start reading docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find all the info you need for authorization with Facebook in their [Facebook Developers reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).

So the URLs you need are probably these:

- Authorization URL: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth (the scopes that can be specified with this URL, can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/))
- Access Token URL: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token