# How to find the **alwasys** up to date Facebook Login API Worlflow URLs

Tags: api, facebook, oauth-2.0

This is additional question in regards to another relevant question:

[Facebook Authorization url, scoped authorization url and token url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326015/6836473)

, I am new to OAuth2.0, so assume I didn't learn literature well back in high school!! (I have seen some people with very short learning curve recommended to read the Facebook login API documentation)

I have looked at it, but didn't find the

> Authorization URL

AND

> Access Token URL

While I was searching for some demos, in one video it used

> https://www.facebook.com/v6.0/dialog/oauth?
> key being: v6.0

in another it used:

> [https://www.facebook.com/v15.0/dialog/oauth?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow)
> key being: v15.0

and in the original post, the kind person who answered seemed to suggest to use:

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
> (which didn't mention the version ID at all, that worked for me, and I like it; easier to remember and use. HOWEVER, previous two also kinda make sense, I don't think Facebook gonna stop enhancing and upgrading its OAuth2 APIs.

and if I go back to the original question, how can I find the latest URL info for above mentioned endpoints?

Thank you a million in advance!!

if this question was too basic, please be tolerant, I am new to OAuth2.0!

Comment: This is the Graph API version you want to use. Which one is the latest, you find under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/versioning

Comment: Thank you @CBroe! the info I saw was a bit outdated, I had to struggle a bit, but now It's resolved.